# Security risk of enabling MSDTC

Tags: security, msdtc

MSDTC is disabled by default (windows 2003 - onwards) and I want to have it enabled for an application I'm developing that requires distributed transactions.

I don't believe there are any security issues with enabling it, but does SF know of any security issues with enabling the DTC?

Cheers

Ollie

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any security issues with enabling MS DTC.  If you require distributed transactions, then you'll need MS DTC, no way around it even if there were.

Comment: Agreed. You can leave it disabled if you don't need it (the less services the better), but there are no reasons to fear it.

Comment: I've used it successfully for many years. Just make sure you are inside a firewall.